# single select box filling in multiple fields (jQ maybe?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box and I'd like to make it fill in fields (something like `<option value="id" data-core="330" data-cco="nosla">id</option>`), would it be possible to fill in `<input type="text">` based on name or id on selection, with data-core going into one and data-cco going into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you could do something like:

```
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
        // this is the selected option:
        var selected = $(this).children('option:selected')[0]
        //input box1:
        $('input.input1').val($(selected).attr('data-core')) 
        //input box2
        $('input.input2').val($(selected).attr('data-cco')) 
    })
})
```

here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KQPxJ/

Comment: thanks, just out of curiosity what is all the $($( for? i haven't used jquery often, sorry if its dumb question. there is no need for getELementByid() or anything?

Comment: i changed my code a bit. $() is how you select a selector on the page in jquery

Comment: Is that all i need ($select.change)? no need to attach event handlers or anything?

Comment: not $select.change. use what i typed above and what is in the example url. jquery has all the handlers.  you might need to wrap in $() i will reflect it in the above code

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, a non jQuery solution (probably much faster although that probably doesn't matter )

```
<form>
    <select name="my_select">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="id" data-core="330" data-cco="nosla">id</option>
    </select><br />
    core<br />
    <input name="input_1"><br />
    cco<br />
    <input name="input_2">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var sel = document.forms[0].my_select;
sel.onchange = function() {
    var selected = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ];
    this.form.input_1.value = selected.getAttribute( 'data-core' ) || '';
    this.form.input_2.value = selected.getAttribute( 'data-cco' ) || '';
}
</script>
```